# Django Multiple Filter with list

Tags: python, django

I have a list of selected items from a MultipleChoiceField object.  After this list is created how can I filter on a Django model table so that it selects all of the items with any of the values in the list?

for example if i selected apples, oranges and strawberries, it returns all of the data from the FruitChoices table where the fruit_name is apples, or oranges, or strawberries.

```
from someApp.models import FruitChoices

def main(form_list):
    r = FruitChoices

    data = {}
    for form in form_list:
        data.update(form.cleaned_data)

        fruits = data['fruit_list']

        for item in fruits:
            result = r.objects.filter(fruit_name__contains='%s' % item)

    return result
```

Comment: Are you intentionally overwriting the result variabl in the loop?

Comment: I'm just using that for an example of what I am trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
import operator
from django.db import Q
r.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(fruit_name__contains=i) for i in fruits)))
```

The reason I recommend this approach is, if you use `__in`, it would match the whole word. But what you are looking for is `__contains` and there is no straight forward way of doing so directly in the ORM. Hence the `Q` objects

This is equivalent of:

```
q_list = []
for x in fruits:
    q_list.append(Q(fruit_name__contains=x)) 
q_filter = "|".join(q_list)
r.objects.filter(q_filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've said

> where the fruit_name is apples, or oranges, or strawberries

and

> so that it selects all of the items with any of the values in the list

but you're using a "*_*_contains" filter.

Do you need to find substrings, ie. "bad strawberries"? If not, you could use the "__in" filter, and cut down the complexity of the entire problem.

```
r.objects.filter(fruit_name__in=data['fruit_list'])
```

Comment: This matches the whole word. Not `contains`.

Comment: Correct @karthikr, but the question was slightly vague as the example he gave was of an equivalence, and the text could be interpreted as not even needing a contains `filter`. This is why I posted this.